# Reference other librarys types/interfaces defined in Typescript .d.ts files

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Edited to try to be more specific (old example removed):

I would like to know how to reference types or interfaces defined in .d.ts files in my own classes and interfaces as types for function parameters or for class attributes.

Here is a example. I will explain some detail that is not completely
relevant to the question but explains the code sample:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var config = require('../config/environment');

class SequelizeDB{
    sequelizeInstance: any;
    sequelize: any;
    modelDirectory: string;
    constructor(Sequelize, dbConfig){  
        //instantiate the sequelize instance object
        this.sequelize  = Sequelize;
        this.sequelizeInstance = this.getDatabaseInstance(this.sequelize,
                                                        dbConfig.databaseName, 
                                                        dbConfig.userName, 
                                                        dbConfig.password, 
                                                        dbConfig.hostName,
                                                        dbConfig.port,
                                                        dbConfig.dialect);
       this.modelDirectory = __dirname + '/sequelize';                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       this.importDataModels();
       this.associateDataModels();
    }
    private getDatabaseInstance(Sequelize,
                        databaseName: string, 
                        userName: string, 
                        password: string, 
                        hostName: string, 
                        port: number, 
                        dialect: string){

        return new Sequelize(
            databaseName, 
            userName,
            password, 
            //options
            {
                host: hostName,
                dialect: dialect,
                port: port,
                pool: {
                    max: 5,
                    min: 0,
                    idle: 10000
            },
        });    
    }
    private importDataModels(){
        //read in all the models from the current folder 
        fs
        .readdirSync(this.modelDirectory)
            .filter((fileName) => {
            return  this.isModelFile(fileName);
        })
        .forEach((file) =>{
            //create the models in the seuelizeInstance
            var model = this.sequelizeInstance.import(path.join(this.modelDirectory, file));
            this[model.name] = model;
        });
    }
    private isModelFile(fileName: string){
        return (fileName.indexOf('.') !== 0) && 
               (fileName !== 'index.js') &&  
               (fileName.indexOf('.map') === -1) &&  //ignore map files
               (fileName.indexOf('.ts') === -1); //ignore ts files
    }
    private associateDataModels(){
        Object.keys(this).forEach((modelName) => {
            if (typeof( this[modelName]) === 'object' &&  'associate' in this[modelName]) {
                this[modelName].associate(this);
            }
       });
    }

};

module.exports = new SequelizeDB(Sequelize, config.sql);
```

I am using Sequelize and I have a pattern set up for
making the creation of the model easy as per their documentation. The
current setup works for me and what the code is doing is creating a class that
that when created sets up a database connection.

It then loops through all the files in the models folder and creates all the models
using Seuquelize.import.

Now what I want to know is how I would be able to replace this part to use the actual
types from the .d.ts file for sequelize (here)[https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/sequelize/sequelize.d.ts].

It appears to me there is a Sequelize static object that is used to create the (lower case) sequelize instance. Like so:

```
new Sequelize(//config values)
```

I want to store these two thing on the class I have created in the code above and currently to make them pass the compiler I have make them of type `any`.

```
sequelizeInstance: any;
sequelize: any;
```

How would I be able to take advantage of the Sequelize .d.ts file that exists and be more explicit about the Type that I expect in that object and the type that is passed to its constructor.

This is not the only example but what I am more generally asking is I can create an interface or a class in TypeScript 
and inforce a function to take that particular class or an interface for example:

```
interface IUser{
    id: number,
    username: string,
    passwork: string    
}

function validateUser(user: IUser): boolean{
    //implementation
}
```

How would I do that if the User interface was defined ina module in node that I installed using npm and have installed using tsd?

Please let me know if this is not enough detail and I will try to explain more.

Comment: Your question is very vague, please explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @gilamran I have updated my question. Let me know if that is not specific enough. It was a general implementation idea that I have been googling for a long time and I'm sure I am just missing something simple.

Comment: Do not use  `var ... require` in Typescript, use `import ... from`, this will also import the definitions

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing would be to use

```
/// <reference path="../typings/sequelize/sequelize.d.ts" />
```

And from that point you will be able to use the interfaces from that d.ts file. Also the compiler will know to include this file in the compilation, so no errors on the missing interfaces.

A most advanced option that you have is to use [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json) (Most IDEs understand this file), and indicating all the files of your project (Including the .d.ts from tsd) inside the **tsconfig.json** and the compiler will "know" what to include in the compilation.

The best thing to do, is actually import the file like this:

```
import * from '../typings/sequelize/sequelize'; // without extension
```

And the compiler will fetch that file before it compiles your code. if it has only ambient declarations (d.ts) it will not include it in the final result (Which is good).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the tsconfig.json option? How would I set those files? Can you just import your main tsd.d.ts? I can't seem to get either of th eother options working  as I thought I had tried those. But I will try again. I feel like there is a massive space in how to correctly do node in Typescript. There is a tiny amount in the docs but not much.